# Usar el Evento Onclick de una página a otra

Tags: javascript, html

Quisiera saber si puedo mandar a llamar o usar un evento `Onclick` de una página, pero desde otra, osea quiero que de una página se direccione a ese evento, o una forma para hacerlo, gracias.

Comment: las 2 paginas estan dentro del mismo host ?

Comment: puedes estudiar sockets , talves con eso puedas hacerlo

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es pasar un parametro en la URL, luego en la otra pagina chequeas por ese parametro, y si existe, activas el click que quieres.

Comment: agrega más detalles a la descripción de tu pregunta

Comment: Hola amigo, seria ideal que indiques que es lo que quieres hacer realmente con un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , es importante que siempre te des a entender al momento de realizar una pregunta, para que te podamos ayudar y solventar el problema. Toma en cuenta que para solventar tu duda tienes que tener el código disponible y ya realizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es lo que entendí puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
<a href="otrapagina.php?id=1">ir a otra pagina y Ejecutar<a>
```

y en la otra página  recibir el id

```
$id $_GET["id"] //obtenemos el parametro

    if($id==1){//ejecutamos el parametro 

      echo"<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        myfuncion();
        })
         </script>";

    }
```